# Objects containing Array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, nullpointerexception

I could assign objects (ingredients) to an array in the main class, like this:

> `Ingredient[] ingredient = new Ingredient[5];`
>   `Ingredient potato = new Ingredient("Potatoes");`
>   `ingredient[0] = potato;`

but what I really want to do is put the array inside another object (food), so I can access it like this:

> `fries.ingredient[0] = potato;`

so that each food has its own collection of ingredients. However, everything I've tried leads to 'NullPointerException' or 'cannot find symbol'. How do I resolve this?

**Edit:**
Sorry for taking a while. I don't know how to indent inside blockquotes, but here goes. This was my (failed) attempt that causes NullPointerException.

Main.java:

> `public class Main {`
>   `public static void main (String[] args) {`
>   `Ingredient potato = new Ingredient("Potatoes");`
>   `Food fries = new Food("Fries");`
>   `fries.ingredient[0] = potato;`
>   `} }`

Food.java:

> `public class Food {`
>   `Ingredient[] ingredient;`
>   `String name;`
>   `public Food(String name) {`
>   `this.name = name;`
>   `Ingredient[] ingredient = new Ingredient[5];`
>   `} }`

Ingredient.java

> `public class Ingredient {`
>   `String name;`
>   `public Ingredient(String name) {`
>   `this.name = name;`
>   `} }`

Comment: Could you show us code that generate this exception/error?

Comment: We can't tell you how to fix your code without seeing neither the the code, nor the error message.

Comment: `A NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required.`
You are trying to access something that doesn't exist, post your code it will help to help you.

Comment: You most likely didn't instantiate Ingredient. You'd have to post more code for us to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor, you have this:

```
Ingredient[] ingredient = new Ingredient[5];
```

You have declared a *local variable* named `ingredient` which shadows your instance variable of the same name. Change that line to

```
this.ingredient = new Ingredient[5];
```

---

As a next step in your learning, consider using a `List<Ingredient>` instead of the array. Arrays are non-resizable, among other inconveniences. Basically, their primary use is in the internals of an implementation, not in client code.

Comment: leads to 'cannot find symbol' for me
edit: nvm, works now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should do that as the following code:

```
Ingredient potato = new Ingredient("Potatoes");
fries = new ClassName(); //Replace with your class Constructor method
fries.ingredient = new Ingredient[5];
fries.ingredient[0] = potato;
```

**Edit:**

Your Food class must be like this:

```
public class Food {
    Ingredient[] ingredient;
    String name;

    public Food(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ingredient = new Ingredient[5];
    }
}
```

and Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ingredient potato = new Ingredient("Potatoes");
        Food fries = new Food("Fries");
        fries.ingredient[0] = potato;
    }
}
```

and Ingredient class

```
public class Ingredient {
    String name;

    public Ingredient(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a class:

```
public class Food{
   public Object[] ingredient;
   public food(int numOfIng){
        this.ingredients=new Object[numOfIng]
   }
}
```

now just do:

```
Food fries=new Food(5);
Ingredient potato = new Ingredient("Potatoes");
fries.ingredient[0] = potato;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do though interface, so as I think something like:

```
interface Food {

   void takeInfo();
}

public class FoodSelection{

private List<Food> listOfFood = new ArrayList<>();

public void selectFries(){
  initFood(new Fries());
}

// other food...

public void initFood(Food food){
food.takeInfo();
listOfFood.add(food);
}

}
```

Now it's time to create fries class..

```
class Fries implements Food{

private String[] ingredients;

public void takeInfo(){
   // declare Fries ingredients.
}

}
```

So, to call it do something like this:

```
FoodSelection takeFood = new FoodSelection();

takeFood.selectFries();
```

Comment: I'll try, but I'm not yet familiar with those keywords

Comment: It will works. And btw the question in your post is answered by Marko Topolnik